# include('includes/countries.php') doesn't work for fake directory

Tags: php, html, url

I'm using a lot of fake directories (or virtual directories or whatever you call it), the include code is:

```
include('includes/countries.php');
```

It works fine in this sample URL (I have a real "list" directory):

```
https://www.sample.com/list/
```

However when it comes to virtual directory like the link below, it doesn't work:

```
https://www.sample.com/list/small/
```

I tried the code below but it still no help:

```
include('./includes/countries.php');
```

Comment: use _ _ DIR _ _ ."/some-relative-path-to/countries.php"

Answer (score 0):

try using `__DIR__` :

```
    include( __DIR__ . '/includes/countries.php');
    // You have to change the path !
```

Comment: what do you mean change the path? I have 1000+ virtual directories.

Comment: just using include is not going to help you . you have set the exact path for your files . because if you don't give a exact path . it will get the path of the main running php file . if you have a lot of directories . you can create a function for including file with __DIR__ and then replace all of your includes with the function .

Comment: I'm giving a full path like this code but it not works, can you edit it: include('/home1/movaz/sample.com/list/../includes/countries.php');

Comment: When you say `include('countries.php')` , it means go to my current location . and give me the `countries.php` but if you include the php file that includes `countries.php` , it's not going to work . so instead of that . you have to say `include( __DIR__ . '/countries.php')` . it means the main directory mathers for us . try using this `include( __DIR__ . '/includes/countries.php');`

Comment: yes, I tried it when the first time I saw your answer but doesn't work

Comment: what is the diffrence between `https://www.sample.com/list/` to `https://www.sample.com/list/small/` ? you change the whole php code or you are using router ?

Comment: I just find this code searching the internet but cant implement it correctly: include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'\\'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'\\includes\\countries.php'); I think the answer is something similar to this.